# Multiple HTTP checks per host with Icinga2

Tags: monitoring, http, icinga2

What is best practice for configuring multiple HTTP checks for a host?

I know there is that "apply" method:

```
apply Service "http" for (http_vhost => config in host.vars.vhosts) {
    ...
}
```

But i do also need the "http_uri" value?!

How to do this via normal config files AND how to do this via the Director?
Where and how i have to modify a template to get multiple HTTP checks linked to a specific host?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the director, but I can tell you how I do this in normal code.
Basically I'd create some dict / list, as you said (at various scopes). There you have to put variables there - those ones you want to change (so for example URL).

So you define a variable with your data. It can be under host, or you can create it in the global scope.

```
globals.http_urls = [ "/uril1", "/url2" ]
```

or

```
object Host "testhost" {
    host.address = 123.123.123.123
    vars.http_urls = [ "/url1", "/url2" ]
}
```

then you can iterate over that variable

```
apply Service "http-url" for (url in globals.http_url) {
    command = http

    # ... other http check variables ...

    vars.http_url = url

    # ... other variables ...

    assign where host.name == "testhost"
}
```

you can also iterate over the dictionary, it works like that:

```
globals.testdict = {
    "server1" : "testdict",
    "server2" : "testweb",
    etc..
}
```

just use **key => value** format in for definition

```
apply Service "http-url" for (server => url in globals.testdict) {
    command = http
    display_name = "http check " + server

    vars.http_url = url
    .. etc

    assign where host.name == testserver
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of Icinga's documentation, but it's explained okayish how to do that in Director.

First, you need to create an array field as explained here: https://icinga.com/docs/icinga-director/latest/doc/14-Fields-example-interfaces-array/

Then you need to create a service apply rule with and add Apply For for your array field, as explained here: https://icinga.com/docs/icinga-director/latest/doc/15-Service-apply-for-example/

Regarding your question

> But i do also need the "http_uri" value?!

That depends. If you leave it, the checked uri will be `/`. I am not sure if it's possible to configure `check_http` with different values for `http_uri` and `http_vhost`.

One thing that confused me a lot is that the parameter `http_uri` of the `check_http` is just the `path` component of the URI. Strange things happen if you try to use a complete URI.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/574824)